# Hadoop Job gets really slow at the last couple of percentage?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have been running jobs on a Hadoop cluster version 0.20.2 and everything was going fine until recently for no reason and without any errors the last couple of percent of map tasks take much longer than the rest of the job, where the last 2% takes 30 seconds and the rest of the job is less than 30 seconds.

This has been happening to all jobs now regardless of input size

here is an example with input data of 4GB, before this problem the entire job from submission to completion was taking 37 seconds but now takes over a minute:

```
14/08/01 20:57:12 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/01 20:57:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201407301409_0033
14/08/01 20:57:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 7% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 21% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 33% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 45% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 54% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 60% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 65% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 87% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 88% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 90% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 92% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 95% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:57:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:58:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:58:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201407301409_0033
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 8
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=19
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=61
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=42
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=4002108148
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=40063116
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=2200000
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
14/08/01 20:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=2200000
```

I was wondering if anyone knows or can explain when or why this would be happening.

BTW I have set the number of reducers to 0 as I don't need them for this job so my job finishes after all map tasks are finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general thing which is noticed when running hadoop jobs.As the map tasks come towards their finish, the results of all map tasks are merged together,which involves combine and sorting of the result.

While the Mapper is still running, the combining and sorting starts in parallel and completes as all map tasks finish.Some maps finish early ,some take longer, depends on the machines' resources, resulting in delay.I would suggest you read the "What happens during Mapping" section of this article I came across while searching for a more technical explanation [link](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2012/01/25/about-the-performance-of-map-reduce-jobs/)

I hope you found this helpful.